# Multiline watch window display for XML data?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debuggervisualizer, xml-visualizer

I'd like to be able to speed up my debugging by being able to view nicely-formatted XML in the VS2010 watch window, as opposed to having everything on a single line.  If I open the XML Visualizer, I have to close it before I can continue execution.  Even a visualizer that can stay open while I'm debugging would be great.  I installed XML Visualizer v.2 on CodePlex to see if it can do this, but it just crashes any time I try to open it.

Does anyone know if this is possible via a VS2010 add-on or similar?